# GlassFish 4 web application deployement

Tags: glassfish

i'm working on a spring web application lately (with spring security and spring data jpa)

I'm getting this error lately and i don't have any idea how to solve it :
when i try to deploy the WAr , i get this :

```
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Set<Service>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager(Set<Service>)]
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
```

any idea what's the problem here ?

EDIT:

here's my pom.xml:

```
 <!--Spring dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- spring security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--com.mysema.querydsl dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
            <version>${com.mysema.querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${com.mysema.querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>${com.mysema.querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Hibernate dependencies-->
         <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--db-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--connection pool-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--thymeleaf and servlet api-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error often comes from **Google Guava 14.x** being packaged in a web application.

You should find out which dependency is responsible for that, and exclude Google Guava from that dependency. Additionally you have to add a newer Guava as dependency, for example:

```
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <version>16.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Update:**

A quick test showed that `querydsl-core` is the the lib which has Guava as dependency. Exclude it like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>${com.mysema.querydsl.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

(And don't forget the new dependency on Guava 16)

**See also:**

- [Issue 1433:  guava 14.0.1 cannot be deployed in a JEE7 Container](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1433)
- [GLASSFISH-20579 - cannot deploy war with google guava lib](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20579)

Comment: i can't really tell which dependency contains that jar, i'll post my pom.xml , can you please tell me which dependency should i edit ?

Comment: unfortunatly, that didn't solve the problem :( but thanks anyway

Comment: Unfortunatly, you obviously didn't `Clean & Build` your project...this solves the problem.