# Intermittent exception starting Glassfish

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, glassfish

I've been intermittently facing exceptions when starting Glassfish from, either, Eclipse plugin or embedded Maven plugin.

I do understand that it must be something related to my project, but unfortunately I couldn't find much, besides cleaning up the project and the target folder and try again(And not even that always solve the problem).

Start-up goal:

```
clean install embedded-glassfish:run
```

Maven plugin configuration:

```
             <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <maxmem>1024</maxmem>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>embedded-glassfish</goalPrefix>
                    <app>target/${project.build.finalName}.war</app>
                    <name>project</name>
                    <precompileJsp>true</precompileJsp>
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <autoCreate>true</autoCreate>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <echo>false</echo>
                    <contextRoot>project</contextRoot>
                    <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.common</groupId>
                        <artifactId>simple-glassfish-api</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
                        <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

**Intermittent Exception:**

```
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer(@Named ClassAnalyzer, IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>)]
```

Does anyone has any clue of what is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: This issue rings a bell with me, I experienced a similar problem when I migrated to GlassFish 4 due to the version of the Google Guava library I was using. Do you have a direct, or indirect, dependency on Guava in your POM? The following question talks about the same problem so may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514679/glassfish-4-web-application-deployement

Comment: Yes I do, it is actually a jersey-client dependency. jersey-guava(2.11) which depends on Google Guava. I will try to make it a direct dependency, just in case. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Well, seems like the issue is related to Eclipse and the way it "kills" Glassfish, either using the IDE plugin or with maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin. When I use glassfish:run and the undeploy option(X, Enter on Console) the problem seems to go away, I will keep searching on how Glassfish handle these situations.